# Saving DOM references outside of renderer class

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, electron, export

I am new to Electron + Typescript so bear with me please.

Currently, I am simply testing what I can do inside of Electron

Issue: I want to manipulate DOM elements outside the renderer. 
I pass the button I add an Eventlistener to as parameter to a function in test.js. This Evenlistener listens to a 'click' event, which will console.log that the button has been pressed. That works perfectly.

Now I add a Textarea. I pass it as parameter as well and save a reference to it in the test. On Click, a function is called that uses this reference to the textArea to console.log the text of the textArea.

Problem: The textArea reference is defined in the function I add the eventlistener in, but outside this function it is undefined. Why, and what can I do to fix it?

renderer.ts

```js
import { test } from "./test";

// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in this process.

let testInstance = new test();
let testButton = document.getElementById("test");
let testArea = document.getElementById("texttest");

console.log(testArea);

testInstance.addEventListenerToButton(testButton, testArea);
```

test.ts

```
export class test{

    textArea;

    addEventListenerToButton(toAddTo, textArea)
    {
        // Defined
        console.log(textArea);
        this.textArea = textArea;
        // Defined
        console.log(this.textArea);
        toAddTo.addEventListener('click', this.showTheText);
        // Defined
        console.log(this.textArea)
    }

    showTheText()
    {
        // Undefined
        console.log(this.textArea);
        console.log(this.textArea.value);
    }
}
```

`Expected: showTheText()` either works, or throws an error about

```
textArea.value
```

> Unexpected: The error is textArea undefined:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.test.showTheText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a reference 'error' (more of a quirk) caused by Javascript itself.

The reference of `this` changes when a function is invoked by an Eventlistener, causing `this` to point to the HTML element instead of the script. Therefore, obviously, it cannot find the reference to the previously saved variable, causing all of these calls to be `undefined` as there simply IS no variable like that on the HTML-Element.

Two Solutions:

1) And my preferred one: use arrow functions on the Eventlistener, that sets a strict context for `this`, solving the issue

```
 toAddTo.addEventListener('click', () => { this.showTheText(); });
```

2) Bind the context to the function. Not sure how that works, but there it is if you wanna google it